# How can I provide credentials for CreateFile (share file)?

Tags: c++, winapi, createfile

My attempt to open a file on a remote machine looks like this:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cwchar>

void main() {
    HANDLE h = CreateFileW (
        L"\\\\10.10.10.10\\c$\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe",
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        nullptr,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        nullptr);
    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::wprintf(L"Error: %u\n", GetLastError());
    } else {
        CloseHandle(h);
    }
}
```

The problem is: it fails and `GetLastError ()` returns 1326 (the username or password is invalid).

What I've tried:

- `NetUseAdd` for IPC$ and C$ with local administrator credentials (both connect successfully)
- `WNetAddConnection2` for IPC$ and C$ with local administrator credentials (both connect successfully)

According to the event log of the remote machine, `CreateFile` attempts to work with the credentials of the user that started the process.

What should I do to make `CreateFile` use the provided credentials?

Yes, I try to connect to the C$ share and it can be done from [Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer).

Comment: What happens if you try to access `\\10.10.10.10\c$\windows\system32\calc.exe` with the Windows Explorer?

Comment: Try an explicit share, rather than `c$`

Comment: @Jabberwocky, as I wrote in original post, it does work.

Comment: @Paul-sanders, I will try, but regardles of the result I need access through C$.

Comment: @Bogudan I mean there is no popup that asks for credentials etc.? What happens with a freshly booted computer?

Comment: @Jabberwocky, in explorer? Yes, there is on 1st connect.

Comment: This question is [discussed at meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424813)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `LogonUser` + `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`.

TL;DR

Most of Windows API that are capable of working with remote machines, usually can be made working mounting `IPC$` share using either `WNetAddConnection*` family or `NetUseAdd`. There are exceptions though.

One of them is `CreateFile`. This function ignores established `IPC$` connections as well as any established connections to shares. You need to use `LogonUser` + `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` pair.

I should point out that the description of `LogonUser` on the MS's site can be misleading. It's correct in saying that *"you cannot use LogonUser to log on to a remote computer"*. What it actually can do is to **prepare** network credentials for future connections to the remote computer. Actual logon will be happening during later API calls (`CreateFile` in this case).